# Is "business of coconut" correct?

Tags: grammar

I know "business selling coconut", but I rather use a preposition like "on", "in", "for" or "of". So is "business of coconut" correct? Why? Also, which one is the most grammatical: on, in, for or of? An easy way would be to say "business selling coconut" or "coconut business", but I want to use a preposition as I have said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be in "the coconut business", or you can be "in the business of selling coconuts".

But "Business of coconut"(*) is not a usual English phrase, because a coconut is kind of tree (or the seed from that tree), not a thing that a business can be made of.